# Why do we have $ \ln(z) = \frac{z-1}{e -1} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ \exp(2^{-n}) +1} {z^{2^{-n}} + 1} $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms, roots, infinite-product

Why do we have

$$ \ln(z) = \frac{z-1}{e -1} \prod_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{ \exp(2^{-n}) +1} {z^{2^{-n}} + 1} $$

Is it possible to show that the derivative of the product is $z^{-1}$ without showing that the product is the logarithm ?

Does that imply there exists a solution set $a_n$ such that :

$$ \ln(z) = \sum (-1)^n a_n z^{1/n} $$

??

Comment: The constraint is harsh. Derivative of an infinite product can't be expressed in a compact way. Unless you take logarithm, but then you will still have a logarithm on the left hand side after differentiating. I don't think there's a way without showing this product converges to the logarithm.

Comment: No idea how to show the derivative is $\frac1z$ but the product itself is very easy to compute (it is a telescoping product)

Comment: Also, you should change the title of the question. The title asks to prove the infinite product for the logarithm, you are asking to prove the derivative